# Isotopes module with chemmacros

Tags: errors, chemistry, chemmacros

I'm trying to use the `Isotopes` module in `chemmacros`package but it doesn't work.

My preamble has:
`\usepackage{chemmacros}` and my documment itself: `\isotope{28,Si}`.

I'm using the version 5.7a of chemmacros. I've already tried to use: `\usechemmodule{all}`, `\IfChemCompatibilityTF{>=}{5.0}`, `\usepackage[compatibility=4.7]{chemmacros}` and other things, but it doesn't work.

The message error is: `Undefined control sequence`.

Comment: What **exact error** do you get? (Which control sequence is undefined…) What about this MWE: `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{chemmacros} \usechemmodule{isotopes} \begin{document} \isotope{14,C} \end{document}`

Comment: `! Undefined control sequence. <recently read> \usechemmodule 
\usechemmodule {isotopes}?`

Comment: Also: `! Undefined control sequence. \isotope {14,C}?`

Comment: Then you do not have a correctly installed version of `chemmacros` v5.7a. Add `\listfiles` at the beginning of the MWE and have a look at the log which version is actually used.

Comment: But something it's strange: I updated the package in MixTeX package manager, and it was installed the last version, but when I did it, I saw it wasn't.

So I updated it myself.

Comment: So everything is fine now?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the comments suggest that the issue was resolved through an update.